# Horrible performance on simple INDEX query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this on a database with 55GB of innodb buffer.
The server is on amazon with EBS 7000 IOPS SSD performance, so quite performant.

The table is 190 GB of data and 116GB of total indexes.

The query runs on an indexed varchar column:

```
 Query   14246   Sending data    select count(*) from profile WHERE name is not null
```

To copy the entire table data to a new location it would need roughly 30 minutes.
But a simple indexed count takes HOURS.

Mysql: Distrib 5.5.42
I can not upgrade, in total I have 2 terrabyte of database storage and upgrading would need it all exported and read in again, so I am locked with that mysql version.

The explain results:

```
1       SIMPLE  profile        NULL    range   name    name    771     NULL    153588811       100.00  Using where; Using index
```

What can I do with this horrible performance ?
I would have expected maybe 5 minutes, not 5 hours ..

Comment: Any change if you use the primary key in count?

Comment: I can try to use the primary key (count(id)) but I was told that * is the right way to do counts in regard of performance.
It will take a while to get results :)
But even if it helps, a fulltable scan should take half an hour, right ?
So why is this thing working since 5 hours ?

Comment: Might be a bug in mysql. Show the table definition anyway,for completion.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Even if the column is not indexed, counting the non-null values shouldn't take hours. How many records do you have in that table?

Comment: about 400 million records

Comment: How long does `count(*)` take?  One possibility is that you got unlucky and there were lots of DML operations while attempting the count.

Comment: Gordon, last time I tried it took about an hour to do a full count.
The thing is: If I would do a simple file copy I could do it in about half an hour.
Which means reading and writing all of the data is multiple times faster than using mysql doing a simple read.

Comment: Never compare file copy to database operations. File copy is a low level OS operation of reading and writing bytes in blocks, there is almost no processing involved. On the other hand, even a simple query like yours involves a good amount of processing, the db engine must collect and parse the data, then applies the calculations required to get the results which must be formatted for display. I'm not saying that one hour is ok for your simple query, it probably should take much less than that, but that has nothing to do with file copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not know how many percent of rows have **name = NULL**. So most time it is much faster to use no index. IF MySQL use a Index the Rows are processed in the order of the index. So this is the reason that MySQL often must read a other block to get the next ROW. This takes much time.

Try a query like this which read all row, but in the physical oder on disc

```
SELECT sum(name is not null) as cnt FROM profile;
```

please let me know it takes affect.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion. I will try that however it does not make me happy.
For once: the whole information is actually in the index. why does it have to search the table at all ?
And is there no way to speed up such statistic counts without forcing fulltable scans ?

Comment: It's roughly 3 times faster than the indexed query. I somehow doubt that a proper solution is possible as that seems a flaw in mysqls internal logic so I accept this one.

Comment: Remark: count(name) only counts rows where name is not null. So I suggested to test the speed of "select count(name) from profile;  ", but my answer was downvoted and deleted. I still don't understand, why?  @triggernz

Answer (score -1):

Please, try:

```
 select count(name) from profile;
```

** Edit: count(name) count rows where name is not Null. Without a WHERE clause, this query might be faster, then the original in the question.
I did not test it's speed with 5.5.42 and large tables.

Comment: I don't have an 5.5.42 server with 2 TB of real world data at hand to test it.  So I actually don't know, how fast it is.

Comment: Any comment about how to improve it without actually testing out it's performance with the above settings?